# Lucene.net set priority for MultiFieldQueryParser

Tags: c#, .net, lucene

Our project uses *Lucene.net* for full text search. In *IndexSearcher* we use *MultiFieldQueryParser* with some fields.
 For example:

```
 var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version, new[] { "ArtNo", "Name", "Description" }, analyzer);
```

I have a problem with returned results. Lucene sorts them by *Sort.RELEVANCE* from all fields. But I need that results by field *'ArtNo'* must be first then *'Name'* and etc, set priority for fields. How to do that trick?

Answer (score 0):

Sorting options are specified in `IndexSearcher` and not in `Query` nor `QueryParser`. You should be able to find searcher being initialized just a few lines below.

Comment: I found in documentation "boost factor", but it didn't work (Lucene 2.9.4.2 ).